# MS Access - Using time values without Date values

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Using expression builder, I built a switch statement that looks like this:

```
Switch([Time]>=#12:00:00 AM# And [Time]<#7:00:00 AM#,"Before 7 am",
[Time]>=#7:00:00 AM# And [Time]<#10:00:00 AM#,"7 am - 9:59 am",
[Time]>=#10:00:00 AM# And [Time]<#5:00:00 PM#,"10 am - 4:59 pm",
[Time]>=#5:00:00 PM# And [Time]<=#9:00:00 PM#,"5 pm - 9 pm",
[Time]>#9:00:00 PM# And [Time]<#11:59:00 PM#,"After 9 pm")
```

But, I noticed my query wasn't working right, so I checked the SQL. Strangely, it looks like this:

```
Switch([Time]>=#12/30/1899# And [Time]<#12/30/1899 7:0:0#,"Before 7 am",
[Time]>=#12/30/1899 7:0:0# And [Time]<#12/30/1899 10:0:0#,"7 am - 9:59 am",
[Time]>=#12/30/1899 10:0:0# And [Time]<#12/30/1899 17:0:0#,"10 am - 4:59 pm",
[Time]>=#12/30/1899 17:0:0# And [Time]<=#12/30/1899 21:0:0#,"5 pm - 9 pm",
[Time]>#12/30/1899 21:0:0# And [Time]<#12/30/1899 23:59:0#,"After 9 pm") 
AS Time_Range
```

So, it looks like Access is converting these to Date/Time values, but I only need the time. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What about writing a custom function for this instead? I think it would be cleaner. As to your problem, there is really no such thing as a date/time that doesn't include a date portion of some kind. You might consider combining your date field (assuming you have one) so that the date is correct. Ideally, I recommend putting Date and Time in the same field and giving it a name that isn't a reserved word in MS Access or the RDBMS that you're using, maybe something like DateTimeEntered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That SQL should work if your [Time] field values include 0 as the whole number (day number) part.  Double-check whether your [Time] values include a non-zero day component.

```
SELECT Format([Time], "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss") AS formatted_date_time
FROM YourTable;
```

If that query shows you [Time] values which include a date other than 12/30/1899, you can use the TimeValue() function to extract the time portions from those values.  (See Access' help topic for details.)  The function will actually give you the same time of day on 12/30/1899, which is day zero.  As HK1 mentioned there is no such thing as a time data type (either for VBA or the db engine); there is only Date/Time, and that **always** includes a day value represented as a whole number of days since day zero (12/30/1899).

**Edit**:  If you're going to use the Switch() function for this, you can simplify it.

```
Switch([Time]<#12/30/1899 7:0:0#,"Before 7 am",
[Time]<#12/30/1899 10:0:0#,"7 am - 9:59 am",
[Time]<#12/30/1899 17:0:0#,"10 am - 4:59 pm",
[Time]<=#12/30/1899 21:0:0#,"5 pm - 9 pm",
[Time]<#12/30/1899 23:59:0#,"After 9 pm") 
AS Time_Range
```

IOW, you don't need to write the second condition as ...

```
[Time]>=#7:00:00 AM# And [Time]<#10:00:00 AM#
```

... because if [Time] is earlier than 7 AM, the first condition would be True, and the second condition wouldn't get evaluated.

**Edit2**: You could use a table for the time brackets instead of using a Switch statement to code them into your SQL.

```
bracket_start  bracket_end  bracket_label
12:00:00 AM     6:59:59 AM      Before 7 am
 7:00:00 AM     9:59:59 AM   7 am - 9:59 am
10:00:00 AM     4:59:59 PM  10 am - 4:59 pm
 5:00:00 PM     9:00:00 PM      5 pm - 9 pm
 9:00:01 PM    11:59:59 PM       After 9 pm

SELECT
    y.[Time],
    b.bracket_label
FROM
    YourTable AS y,
    time_brackets AS b
WHERE
        y.[Time] >= b.bracket_start
    AND y.[Time] <= b.bracket_end;
```

**Edit3**: I would prefer the time_brackets table approach (Edit2) over the Switch() expression in your query.  The table approach will be easier to maintain if you have more than one query like this in the event you ever decide to change the time brackets and/or the bracket labels.  Simply change the time_brackets table instead of revising a Switch() expression in each query.

That consideration may not be compelling if you're only doing this for a single query.  However, in that case, I would still prefer the table approach because I find it more challenging to write complex Switch() expressions error-free.  The same argument would also apply (even more so!) if we were considering a nested IIf() expression instead of Switch().

Finally, the bracket time ranges and labels constitute data.  And data rightfully belongs in tables.  Wherever practical, I prefer to avoid coding data into SELECT statements.  That means I look for ways to avoid Switch() or nested IIf() expressions in queries.  And an incidental benefit here is that the query designer will not rewrite your Switch() statement as it did for you when you don't have a Switch() statement.  :-)

Comment: I tried the first approach and it worked perfectly. Thanks Hans!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some additional suggestions...

If your [Time] values may contain a whole number (day) component other than zero, you might try the following variation of @HansUp's suggestion:

```
Switch(Hour([Time])<7,"Before 7 am",
Hour([Time])<10,"7 am - 9:59 am",
Hour([Time])<17,"10 am - 4:59 pm",
Hour([Time])<=21,"5 pm - 9 pm",
Hour([Time])<=23,"After 9 pm") 
AS Time_Range
```

Alternatively, if you want to enforce the assumption that the [Time] values *do not* contain a whole number component, you might might set the "Validation Rule" property of the field in the underlying table (if there is one) to:

```
>=0 And <1
```

Comment: Because otherwise "Date" values can be assigned values less than zero.  Negative numbers are possible -- they just represent days before Dec. 30, 1899.