# Split date and time database access in C#

Tags: ms-access

I am using a Access database to save data from my database. Now, I have a table with date and time in different columns but I not able to get only the time.

I have a query to insert values into the database

```
INSERT INTO tblUsers(ID, Name, Date, Time) VALUES (@ID, @Nome, Date(), Now())
```

But using Now() it will give me Date and Time values.

So do you have any ideia how could I solve it?

Comment: What are the precise types of those columns? And isn't this really an Access issue rather than C#, given that there's no C# involved in your code?

Comment: You have a number of reserved words, this will cause you pain. Now is date and time, Format is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

To convert  Now() to a Date only you can use the DateValue function. See ([here](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datevalue.php)) for examples.

To get time values without dates values see this ([accepted answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810357/ms-access-using-time-values-without-date-values))

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in c# and Time field is string, you can get the time with this code:

{
...
string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");

INSERT INTO tblUsers(ID, Name, Date, Time) VALUES (@ID, @Nome, Date(), timeStamp)

...

}

If is a Time typed field, you can use TimeOfDay it returns one timeStamp structure compatible with time fields.

{
...
string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

INSERT INTO tblUsers(ID, Name, Date, Time) VALUES (@ID, @Nome, Date(), timeStamp)

...

}

I've hope helped.